# Underscore.js groupBy two levels

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I can't seem to word this properly by I need to group by `date` and `foo`:

```
// Using date as numbers for clear example
// date key should be grouped into a key
// Under that key (date), I should see another key of "foo"

let list = [
  { date: "1", foo: "me", result: "meFoo"},
  { date: "1", foo: "me2", result: "meYou"},
  { date: "1", foo: "me3", result: "meHe"},
  { date: "2", foo: "me", result: "meHim"},
  { date: "2", foo: "me2", result: "meHim"}
]

let grouped = _.groupBy(list, "date") // keys ie 1, 2

// I need another key under the date key, possible?
let grouped = _.groupBy(list, "date", (val) => _.groupBy(val), "foo") // result not expected
```

I'm getting a bit complex here so I used underscore to ease the complexity. Is this possible?

I'll then do something like, I could use `_.pluck`:

```
Object.keys(grouped).map( dateKey => Object.keys(grouped[dateKey]).map(fooKey => console.log( grouped[dateKey][fookey][0] )) )
```

That really looks wrong on the highest level.

Expected results to look something like:

```
DATE // key
 |
 |___ FOO // key
       |
       |__ array foo objects
```

Comment: Or you could just make 1 single for loop that groups by 2 levels. Faster and much easier to read.

Comment: @Rudie An example? I've tried two groupBy and nothing works or expected

Comment: you have the same items with same `date` and `foo`. please add a wanted result.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. Ive updated

Comment: @Sylar The procedural example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47473898/247372 is what I meant. Much more readable and faster than https://stackoverflow.com/a/47473679/247372

Comment: @Rudie I see what you mean. Yes it does; Ive just tried it. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the desired array.

```
_.map(_.groupBy(list, 'date'), (value, key) => ({[key]: _.groupBy(value, 'foo')}))
```

I hope you want such result:

```js
var list = [{ date: "1", foo: "me", result: "meFoo" }, { date: "1", foo: "me2", result: "meYou" }, { date: "1", foo: "me3", result: "meHe" }, { date: "2", foo: "me", result: "meHim" }, { date: "2", foo: "me2", result: "meHim" }],
    grouped = _.map(_.groupBy(list, 'date'), (value, key) => ({[key]: _.groupBy(value, 'foo')}));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it looks, you need for every level a new mapping?

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the edit and I'm sorry, I didn't get your point

Comment: i mean, you need for every nested grouping a another `groupBy`.

Comment: Yeah, That might be a little expensive

Comment: But I personally feel good and understandable code is better than a code which is not readable but very optimised. There can be a trade off

Answer (score 5):

#### Functional (using reduce):

```
list.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const key1 = item.date
  const group1 = acc[key1] || {}
  const key2 = item.foo
  const group2 = group1[key2] || []
  return {
    ...acc,
    [key1]: {
      ...group1,
      [key2]: group2.concat(item)
    }
  }
}, {})
```

#### Procedural:

```
let grouped = {}

list.forEach((item) => {
    // Create an empty object if this key has not already been set:
    grouped[item.date] = grouped[item.date] || {}

    // Create an empty list if this key has not already been set:
    grouped[item.date][item.foo] = grouped[item.date][item.foo] || []

    // Push the item to our group:
    grouped[item.date][item.foo].push(item)
})
```

In python this would be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

_list = [
    {"date":"1","foo":"me","result":"meFoo"},
    {"date":"1","foo":"me2","result":"meYou"},
    {"date":"1","foo":"me3","result":"meHe"},
    {"date":"2","foo":"me","result":"meHim"},
    {"date":"2","foo":"me2","result":"meHim"}
]

grouped = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for item in _list:
    grouped[item['date']][item['foo']].append(item)
```

Comment: I'll translate it to a procedural pattern in a moment

Comment: That reduce is freakin' cool! And only possible with very new browsers. Spread operator for objects only works in Chrome 60+ and Firefox 55+.

Comment: Thanks @Rudie. Note that the arrow functions are also part of ES6. It seems to me though that most modern web applications leverage compilers such as babel. Personally I would not want to be without the latest advances in ecmascript. I, personally, only ever regress to ES5 for tiny projects and prototypes.

Comment: In my case, the second level only has one item per group where I was expecting plenty. Does the code assume that there will only be one record per `date`|`foo` "path" ?

Comment: @Chapo there was a bug in the original code.  Answer has been edited to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there. For the second level of grouping you need to map across the values of the first grouping:

```
let result = _.chain(list)
    .groupBy('date')
    .mapObject( grp => _.groupBy(grp, 'foo'))
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve this using `function` composition. I have used [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) library for this. First, group it via date and then group it via foo. Also, please note that I didn't find any curried function for iterating object keys, that is why I added it myself.

```js
let list = [
  { date: "1", foo: "me", result: "meFoo"},
  { date: "1", foo: "me2", result: "meYou"},
  { date: "1", foo: "me3", result: "meHe"},
  { date: "2", foo: "me", result: "meHim"},
  { date: "2", foo: "me2", result: "meHim"},
  { date: "2", foo: "me2", result: "meHimAnother"}
]

function iterKeys(fn) {
  return function(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
      obj[key] = fn(obj[key])
    }
    return obj;
  }
}

var group = R.compose(iterKeys(R.groupBy(R.prop('foo'))), R.groupBy(R.prop('date')))
console.log(group(list));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```